# Plato's tripartite soul and Chariot Allegory

Tags: plato, emotions, souls, platonism

I liked Plato's [tripartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato%27s_theory_of_soul) soul theory but am confused with its [analogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chariot_Allegory) of the chariot.
Maybe I am missing some good definitions.

- I very well understand that logos is related to the charioteer.
- But the "the thymos (θυμοειδές), or thumetikon (emotion, spiritedness, or masculine)" I don't understand which horse it relates to? Because according to my understanding thymos here is related to emotion in general **which can be both negative and positive**, but one of the horses, white one, is positive by definition (e.g. from wiki:"one of the horses is noble and of noble breed").
- This part I also agree with I think that "the eros (ἐπιθυμητικόν), or epithumetikon (appetitive, desire, or feminine)" is related to black horse.

It seems I have problem with second bullet point. Can someone help me clarify the confusion?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a mistake to correlate the analogy of the chariot and two horses exactly with the Republic's tripartition of the soul. In the Phaedrus:

> All three capacities, and
>    not only a rational part of the soul, are given an essential and positive
>    role in striving toward the good and the beautiful, and each capacity is
>    represented as having certain defects. Although the three capacities have
>    some similarity to the three parts of the soul in Republic 4 - reason, appetite, and spirit - they should not simply be equated with these parts,
>    for all three capacities share to some extent in reason and all three have
>    desires. The charioteer represents a guiding principle in the soul, with
>    desires of its own. The black horse represents an impulse to move in
>    bold and disorderly fashion toward erotic objects, while the white horse
>    represents the impulse to stand still and to resist these objects. Both
>    horses are able to use and to follow reason and are therefore capable
>    of being trained by the charioteer, who must also train himself to guide  them without imposing excessive restraint or yielding to the impulse to
>    move forward without any restraint. In this myth, all three capacities of
>    the human soul share in a divine, winged element, and all three also have
>    bestial characteristics. The black horse, then, is not innately evil but can
>    be a force for good if he is properly trained. Without the guidance of the
>    charioteer, the black horse moves in shameless and disorderly fashion,
>    bending his head, stretching out his tail, taking the bit in his teeth, and
>    dragging the chariot shamelessly forward in pursuit of an erotic object
>    (254d6-7). After he is tamed, however, the black horse helps to move
>    the chariot in an orderly way toward the beloved, that is, with reverence
>    and fear (...254e9).

(Elizabeth Belfiore, 'Dancing with the Gods: The Myth of the Chariot in Plato's "Phaedrus"', The American Journal of Philology, Vol. 127, No. 2 (Summer, 2006), pp. 185-217: 190-1.)

In the Phaedrus all three capacities come into agreement with one another, with the result that there is order in the soul, but this occurs only after a rough journey throughout which the soul lacks all stability. Key point: the three capacities operate in the charioteer and the two horses: '*thymos* (θυμοειδές) or *thumetikon*' invades the charioteer and both horses - all three players - at different stages of the journey. Specifically and *en route*, it cannot be 'located' in either horse. The following extract is long but the story can't be shortened:

> 1. The process begins when the charioteer, seeing the beloved, warms
>      the whole soul, causing it to be filled with tickling and desire (253e5-
>      254a1). Although the stimulus comes first to the charioteer, all three
>      parts of the soul have the same emotional response, characterized
>      earlier as a boiling and tickling (251c4-5), resulting from the growth
>      of the feathers, that affects the entire soul (251b6-7).
> 2. The three parts of the soul act differently in response to the same
>      emotional stimulus. The white horse "compelled then and always by
>      *aidos*, restrains himself from leaping upon the beloved" (254al-3).
>      The black horse, however, is himself carried away by force and in
>      turn compels (254a5, bl) the white horse and the charioteer to approach the beloved and to mention the pleasures of sex (254a3-7).
>      They at first resist (254a7-bl). Finally, however, the white horse and
>      charioteer yield and agree to do what the black horse orders, and
>      they approach the beloved (254b1-4).
> 3. When they are forced to draw near to the beloved, the charioteer
>      sees his beauty and remembers the true beauty he saw in a previous
>      existence (254b4-7).That is, he has the experience that was said earlier (249d4-e4) to be the madness and enthusiasm of the lover, who,
>      seeing beauty here, is reminded of beauty there. As a result of this
>      vision, the charioteer experiences reverence and fear (254b7-8).
> 4. Approach is followed by retreat. The charioteer is now compelled to
>      pull back strongly on the reins so that both horses sit back on their
>      haunches. The white horse obeys willingly and without resisting; the
>      black horse obeys but much against his will. The two horses then
>      retreat (254b8-c4).
> 5. The two horses react differently after the retreat. The white horse
>      experiences shame and terror, and he waters the whole soul with
>      sweat (254c4-5). This horse experiences not *aidos*, the good kind of
>      shame that restrains him from leaping upon the beloved, but *aischyne*,
>      shame at having done wrong in yielding to the black horse. When
>      the black horse recovers from pain, he becomes angry and abusive
>      and tries, without success, to force the others to approach the beloved
>      again. Finally, the black horse grudgingly agrees with the others to
>      postpone a second approach (254c5-d2). This stage of the conflict
>      ends in a temporary truce.
> 6. The whole process of approach and retreat is repeated a second time
>      (254d2-e5) and many times (*pollakis*, 254e6) thereafter. The black
>      horse again compels the others to approach, pulling shamelessly to?
>      ward the beloved, and the charioteer again pulls back on the reins.
>      On these subsequent occasions, however, the charioteer's experience
>      is more powerful (*eti mallon*, 254e1), and he pulls more strongly on
>      the reins of the hubristic horse (*eti mallon*, 254e2). The white horse
>      is not mentioned.
> 7. At last the black horse is tamed (*tapeinotheis*). He ceases from *hybris*
>      and obeys the charioteer, feeling extreme fear at the sight of the
>      beloved (254e6-8).
> 8. The final result of the whole process is that the whole soul of the
>      lover follows the beloved with *aidos* and fear (...254e8-255al). This process results not only in the taming of the black horse but also in a permanent - or at least semi-permanent - agreement of all three parts of the soul. The charioteer is in command,
>      and the two horses obey willingly. The whole soul now experiences
>      both the aidos that was at first a characteristic of the white horse
>      alone and the fear (*dediduian*, 254e9) that the charioteer originally
>      experienced when he remembered true beauty at the sight of the
>      beloved (*edeise*, 254b7) and that the black horse experienced while
>      being tamed (254e8). The motion toward the beloved that the black
>      horse once forced upon the others has now been imparted to the
>      whole soul so that it follows the beloved in orderly fashion. In this
>      way, the lover, having transformed disorder into order in his soul,
>      begins to follow his god.

(Belfiore: 192-4.)